# Find a process id of a runaway php script

Tags: php, pid

I accidentally set up an infinite loop in a php script that's writing to a txt file at about 100mb a minute. It's been going almost half an hour now, so I am deleting the file every couple of minutes until I figure out how to kill the process.

How do I view and find the specific PID for the process?

And if other people are using the script (they aren't caught in the same loop though), how will I know which PID is the offending one so I don't kill anyone else's process?

I have access to the VPS server. I've contacted the server admin guy, but it may be a while before he gets back.

THANKS!

Comment: if you have command line access `top` should tell you

Comment: ps -aux | grep "php" can also help

Answer (score -1):

you can try `top` like @Dragon said, or `htop`, which better visual